# Tailwind - Flex row children don't grow in height

Tags: css, flexbox, tailwind-css

I have the following:

`.flex .flex-row
    .flex #1
    .flex #2`

both flex boxes are the same height. When the content of `.flex #2` changes the height of both flex boxes does also leaving a lot of empty space at the bottom of  `.flex #1`

How can I prevent this and instead cause the content of `.flex #2` to scroll?

I don't want to set any fixed heights, would like height of `.flex #2` to always remain the same as the height of `.flex #1`'s content.

Comment: You should supply a example so we can see the context of your code :)

Comment: Usually stretch is the default, but I guess tailwind  changes that

Answer (score 7):

I think you're looking for [`.items-stretch`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/align-items#stretch).

**Example:** (because you didn't add some code from yourself)

```
<div class="flex items-stretch bg-gray-200 h-24">
  <div class="flex-1 text-gray-700 text-center bg-gray-400 px-4 py-2 m-2">1</div>
  <div class="flex-1 text-gray-700 text-center bg-gray-400 px-4 py-2 m-2">2</div>
  <div class="flex-1 text-gray-700 text-center bg-gray-400 px-4 py-2 m-2">3</div>
</div>
```

**Will result same div heights:**
[image: same div heights based on .items-stretch]